# Is there and API for Google Plus Collections?

Tags: api, google-plus

Is the an API to post updates into a G+ Collection?

https://plus.google.com/collections/welcome

Comment: There's no Google plus API that allow post collection from external application, Google plus API only allow to list all of the activities in the specified collection for a particular which you can read here https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list#try-it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's isn't any G+ API that lets you post to G+, including collections, communities and in general.  This excludes the Google+ Domains API which can write but not like the regular G+ API.